# Gradient of the function $f(x)= \|x\|^p$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

How can the gradient in this case be computed? I understand that 
$f(x)= (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots + x_N^2)^{p/2}$ but how do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

- Recall the definition of the gradient.
- Recall the definition of partial derivative.
- Recall how to compute the derivative of $(x^2 + C)^{p/2}$.